# Symfony 301 redirect in the controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, redirect

I have an entity `Event` with parameters `id` and `slug` in my Symfony app. 
Parameter `slug` is nullable and not required so, if it missing, link to the single event page builds using `id`. But, if `slug` is set, url is build using this parameter.

The task is to create 301 redirect for the events which are have slug. I'm, trying to use symfony method `redirect()` but I encountered a problem: when I set slug for the first time, it works fine and replaced me from the url `event/3` to `event/my-event-slug`. But when I removing slug or change it browser are still redirecting my to my first slug which was provided.

I'm checking it in Chrome console and it shows to me that my redirect 301 was loaded from cache.

How can I prevent saving redirect to the cache or how can I solve this problem in another way in controller?

Comment: 301s are explicitly permanent, hence cached. If you don't want this, use a 302

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
return $this->redirect($url, 301);
```

Comment: Yes, I try this way and in this case redirect was saved in cache.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$object = new Event();

        $router = $this->get('router');

        $url = $object->getSlug() ? $router->generate('my_route', $object->getSlug()) : $router->generate('my_route', $object->getId());

        $this->redirect($url,301);
```